# HTML5-video : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I have a simple sidebar in which I have a list of videos. Now I want to add custom play button so that user can play a video of his choice. It looks like this.

[image]

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="sidebar navbar-nav" id="canvas" tabindex="1" style="overflow: hidden; outline: none;">

    <div id="51" class="sidebar_movie-block ui-draggable" style="position: relative;">
        <h1 class="title" for="video_51">Ecommerce</h1><span class="block-edit fa fa-edit" for="video_51"></span>
        <div class="playpause" for="video_51"></div>
        <video id="video_51" movieid="51" class="video-list video" src="videos/mena.mp4" duration="14.984" frames="375"></video>
    </div>

    <div id="10" class="sidebar_movie-block ui-draggable" style="position: relative;">
        <h1 class="title" for="video_10">Travel</h1><span class="block-edit fa fa-edit" for="video_10"></span>
        <div class="playpause" for="video_10"></div>
        <video id="video_10" movieid="10" class="video-list video" src="videos/whats_your.mp4" duration="3.344" frames="84"></video>
    </div>

    <div id="12" class="sidebar_movie-block ui-draggable" style="position: relative;">
        <h1 class="title" for="video_12">CRM</h1><span class="block-edit fa fa-edit" for="video_12"></span>
        <div class="playpause" for="video_12"></div>
        <video id="video_12" movieid="12" class="video-list video" src="videos/and_in.mp4" duration="5.104" frames="128"></video>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is the js code for playing the video:

```
var myVideo = $(".sidebar_movie-block").find("video").attr('id');
            console.log(myVideo);
            // $("#" + myVideo).play();
            $(".playpause").on('click', function(){
                  $(myVideo).get[0].play();            
            })
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the following error!

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is play the video when button next to it is clicked then all you have to do is get the reference to video element by getting the parent div and finding the video element. Try this:

```
$(".playpause").on('click', function(){
   $(this).closest('.sidebar_movie-block').find('video').get(0).play();            
});
```

Comment: Hi nawed I still get the error here is live demo https://videomill-bot.audiencevideo.com/editor/   check it yourself

Comment: Are you trying to just play the video next to the playpause button?

Comment: Yes, as you can see I just want to play  the video by clicking the play button

Comment: Please make sure you add the .get(0) that I added after i wrote the comment.

Comment: Now works, just needed to  add closet('.sidebar_movie-block')